# Lists: changing values, seriously what is going on here?

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array

I have a simple two-dimensional List in python. I create it by reading in a text file, line by line, and using the .split() method to divide it up, convert to float, and all seems fine. I immediately print the list, index by index and it looks good. I do it a second time, and suddenly it only contains what was in the last index of the original list.
Except for the split() and float assignment I literally copied the code from the top loop to make the second loop:

```
dataLinesStr = ["1 2 3 4 5", "6 7 8 9 10", "11 12 13 14 15", "16 17 18 19 20", "21 22 23 24 25"]
numLines = len(dataLinesStr)
numPix = 5
lineData = [[0.0] * numPix] * numLines  # Refer as:  lineData[numLines][numPix]
r = 0
while r < numLines:
    tmpStr = dataLinesStr[r].split()  # a list of strings.
    p = 0
    while p < numPix:
        lineData[r][p] = float(tmpStr[p])
        if r < 3: print("[" + str(r) + "][" + str(p) + "]lineData = ", lineData[r][p])
        p += 1
    r += 1

print("2nd time....")
r = 0
while r < numLines:
    p = 0
    while p < numPix:
        if r < 3: print("[" + str(r) + "][" + str(p) + "]lineData = ", lineData[r][p])
        p += 1
    r += 1
```

Output is:

```
[0][0]lineData =  1.0
[0][1]lineData =  2.0
[0][2]lineData =  3.0
[0][3]lineData =  4.0
[0][4]lineData =  5.0
[1][0]lineData =  6.0
[1][1]lineData =  7.0
[1][2]lineData =  8.0
[1][3]lineData =  9.0
[1][4]lineData =  10.0
[2][0]lineData =  11.0
[2][1]lineData =  12.0
[2][2]lineData =  13.0
[2][3]lineData =  14.0
[2][4]lineData =  15.0
2nd time....
[0][0]lineData =  21.0
[0][1]lineData =  22.0
[0][2]lineData =  23.0
[0][3]lineData =  24.0
[0][4]lineData =  25.0
[1][0]lineData =  21.0
[1][1]lineData =  22.0
[1][2]lineData =  23.0
[1][3]lineData =  24.0
[1][4]lineData =  25.0
[2][0]lineData =  21.0
[2][1]lineData =  22.0
[2][2]lineData =  23.0
[2][3]lineData =  24.0
[2][4]lineData =  25.0
```

There are no variable manipulations between the two loops, yet only the last element in the original list is present in the second loop.  I've been going nutz over this.  I can't see a mutable vs. nonmutable reason this is occurring. Anyone see what's wrong here to produce this?

Comment: `lineData = [[0.0] * numPix]` This creates many identical references to the same object.  When you change one, you change them all, because they're _the same object_.

Comment: Thank you and thank you to who ever linked this question to the past one answered.  A subtly learned.